# Canvas installation in another SalesForce works but can't find button in Chatter

Tags: chatter, canvas, iframe

I have created a Canvas app and it runs perfectly on SF developer account 1.
In SF developer account 1 it appears on the Chatter tab as a button in the left menu (classic mode).
I create a package and upload it.
I then login to SF developer account 2 to install the Canvas app from the installation URL.
It says installation worked for SF developer account 2.
The canvas app appears in the App menu; however when I select it, nothing happens.
No error message, no iframe container and it does not appear as a button in the left menu of the Chatter tab so that users can launch it.

Can someone please provide a solution or things to try?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Wow SalesForce, this is painful (very frustrating system).  I switched to SF Developer 2 account and tried to setup another package; but it said I already had one (did not) and SF limits you to one managed package. So I created a Namespace and then I was able to create a Managed package for my Canvas app.  I uploaded it and installed it on SF Developer 1.

The install message warned my that it was a Beta app and blah, blah, blah. So I accepted the warnings and it worked, well kinda.  If you have 2 accounts, SF gets confused and refused to run the canvas app on SF Developer 1...so I checked the Chrome browser dev console and there is an error message regarding an X Frame issue? I click the URL in the Chrome console and I get the expected Oauth dialog.  I then Allow the new app to run and everything is peachy.

So try the Namespace thing if your canvas app does not appear in a button in the left menu/sidebar.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/namespaces_creating.htm#!